# Bazel tries to download a hash-named file

Tags: bazel

I get a warning during bazel build:

```
WARNING: Download from https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/0d5f3f2768c6ca2faca0079a997a97ce22997a0c.zip failed: ...
```

I don't care why this file can't be downloaded. (I know why)
**But my question is:** What's this file? what is it for? and why its name is hashed?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This zipfile contains the C++ rules for Bazel. The hash refers to the commit which the zipfile is built from. You can find the source from https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc.

While the C++ rules are currently implemented in core Bazel with Java, native rules for C++, Android and Java are incrementally rewritten in Starlark and hosted on repositories on GitHub.

Some of the other rulesets include:

- https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_java
- https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_android
- https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala